# Derivative of Integral (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

**Question**: Suppose $F(x) = \int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{\cos t} dt$. Find the derivative of $F(x)$ over the region $x\in[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$ for which it is continuous.

**Attempt:** So I know how to do the following computations:
$$\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{\cos(t)} dt = \int^{x^2}_0 \sec(t)dt$$
$$\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{\cos(t)} dt = [\ln|\tan(t)+\sec(t)|]^{x^2}_0$$
$$\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{\cos(t)} dt = \ln|\tan(x^2)+\sec(x^2)| - \ln|\tan(0)+\sec(0)|$$
$$\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{\cos(t)} dt = \ln|\tan(x^2)+\sec(x^2)| - \ln1$$
$$\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{\cos(t)} dt = \ln|\tan(x^2)+\sec(x^2)|$$

Note: To find $\int \sec(t) dt$ I used the method of substitution found [here](http://www.math.com/tables/integrals/more/sec.htm).

And then using the chain rule to differentiate ($u=|\tan(x^2)+\sec(x^2)|$ so $F(x)=\ln u$), we get $F'(x)=\frac{2x}{\cos (x^2)} = 2x\sec (x^2)$ for $x\in[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$.

However, this question was given in a real analysis course and I believe I need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (which is fine considering $F$ is continuous for $x\in[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$ as stated in the question so not required to prove).

I am familiar with two different (but equivalent) definitions of the FTC; [this one](https://i.ibb.co/2j0wxPj/Screen-Shot-2020-05-15-at-12-01-57-PM.png) and [this one](https://i.ibb.co/3pwwP3G/Screen-Shot-2020-05-15-at-12-02-16-PM.png), but am unsure of which one to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (second link in your question) with chain rule.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh would I need to use the FTC with the substitution method where I evaluated $\int \sec(t) dt$?

Comment: No the FTC allows you to calculate desired derivative without evaluating the integral. That's what makes things easy.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Without evaluating the integral? Does that mean the computations where I evaluated $\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{\cos t} dt$ were unnecessary? I don't understand how that could be because how could you get the $\ln|\tan(x)+\sec(x)|$ from the FTC?

Comment: Yes all that work is unnecessary (you have even made a mistake in evaluation, the upper limit is $x^2$ not $x$). The question does not ask you to evaluate the integral but rather to evaluate $F'(x) $. You can see the answer by Clement Yung which evaluates $F'(x) $ without evaluating $F(x) $ (the integral in question).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok, thank you for your help!

Comment: The last two links in the question are broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}[1]{\; \mathrm{d} #1}$
Write:
$$
G(x) = \int_0^x \sec{t} \d{t}
$$
FTOC then tells us that $G'(x) = \sec{x}$. Furthermore, by chain rule we know that:
$$
(f \circ g)' (x) = g'(x) f'(g(x))
$$
Therefore, let $H(x) = x^2$, and we have that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_0^{x^2} \sec{t} \d{t} &= (G \circ H)'(x)  \\
&= H'(x)G'(H(x)) \\
&= 2x\sec{x^2}
\end{align*}